# comparing two double arrays, and then printing the number of differences + largest difference

Tags: java, arrays, double

I have two arrays that have double values.

```
double[] testArray1 = {3.3, 2.7, 6.4, 1.8, 9.5, 1.4, 9.0, 7.0, 6.5, 3.7};
double[] testArray2 = {5.6, 4.7, 2.8, 3.7, 5.8, 2.7, 6.4, 1.8, 9.5,10.2};
```

I need to compare the values and then print the number of differences as well as the highest difference. So far, I've done this;

```
    double nDiff = 0;
    double BiggestDiff = 0;
    double currentDiff = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < testArray1.length; i++){
      for (int k = 0; k < testArray1[i].length; k++){
        if (testArray1[i][k] != testArray2[i][k]) {
          nDiff +=;
          currentDiff = 0;

          if (testArray1[i][k] > testArray2[i][k]) {
            nDiff = (testArray1[i][k] - testArray2[i][k]);
          }
          else {
            currentDiff = (testArray2[i][k] - testArray1[i][k]);
          }
          if (currentDiff > BiggestDiff) {
            BiggestDiff = currentDiff;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (nDiff > 0) {
      System.out.println("Number of differences was " + nDiff);
      System.out.println("The biggest difference was " + BiggestDiff);
    }
```

first, I get an **illegal start of expression** error that points to the **;** in `nDiff +=;`. So I remove that only to get several errors telling me **double cannot be dereferenced** and **array required, but double found** which makes me think I've done the code wrong entirely.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about `nDiff += 1;` or simply `nDiff++;`? And reserve strings starting with a capital letter for class names, whereas instances of that class start with a lowercase letter according to java convention.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all: `for (int k = 0; k < testArray1[i].length; k++){` is wrong. When you call testArray1[i] it returns double number not array, you can't get length property of single double number.
2. Next: `testArray1[i][k] != testArray2[i][k]` these arrays are not matrixes, so you cant have double brackets here like [][], if you want to take element from array it should be just testArray[i].
3. nDiff += ; plus what? You have to put here something after += like                     `nDiff += k;`
4. You want to compare 1st element vs 1st element, 2v2, 3v3 etc.? Or every element from first array with every element from second array?

If every x every then your code should be like:

```
        double[] testArray1 = {3.3, 2.7, 6.4, 1.8, 9.5, 1.4, 9.0, 7.0, 6.5, 3.7};
        double[] testArray2 = {5.6, 4.7, 2.8, 3.7, 5.8, 2.7, 6.4, 1.8, 9.5, 10.2};

        double biggestDifference = 0;
        double differenceCounter = 0;
        double currentDifference;

        double firstArrayValue;
        double secondArrayValue;

        for (int i = 0; i < testArray1.length; i++){
            for (int k = 0; k < testArray1.length; k++){
                firstArrayValue = testArray1[i];
                secondArrayValue = testArray2[k];
                if (firstArrayValue != secondArrayValue) {
                    differenceCounter += 1;
                    currentDifference = Math.abs(firstArrayValue - secondArrayValue);
                    if (currentDifference > biggestDifference) {
                        biggestDifference = currentDifference;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (differenceCounter > 0) {
            System.out.println("Number of differences was " + differenceCounter);
            System.out.println("The biggest difference was " + biggestDifference);
        }
```

Then it will print:

```
Number of differences was 95.0
The biggest difference was 8.799999999999999
```

If you want to compare 1v1, 2v2, 3v3 etc. you can assume that both arrays have same lenght, then you should use one index like:

```
        double[] testArray1 = {3.3, 2.7, 6.4, 1.8, 9.5, 1.4, 9.0, 7.0, 6.5, 3.7};
        double[] testArray2 = {5.6, 4.7, 2.8, 3.7, 5.8, 2.7, 6.4, 1.8, 9.5, 10.2};

        double biggestDifference = 0;
        double differenceCounter = 0;
        double currentDifference;

        double firstArrayValue;
        double secondArrayValue;

        if (testArray1.length == testArray2.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < testArray1.length; i++) {
                    firstArrayValue = testArray1[i];
                    secondArrayValue = testArray2[i];
                    if (firstArrayValue != secondArrayValue) {
                        differenceCounter += 1;
                        currentDifference = Math.abs(firstArrayValue - secondArrayValue);
                        if (currentDifference > biggestDifference) {
                            biggestDifference = currentDifference;
                        }
                    }
            }
            if (differenceCounter > 0) {
                System.out.println("Number of differences was " + differenceCounter);
                System.out.println("The biggest difference was " + biggestDifference);
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Sorry, arrays have different length :(");
        }
```

Then it will print:

```
Number of differences was 10.0
The biggest difference was 6.499999999999999
```

You should use normal IDE like InteliJ or Eclipse, it will show you compile time errors. Cheers.

Comment: differenceCounter should not be double since number of differences  imply that it is an positiv non fractional value. So there should be int used. The next question is if the teacher expect that he order is relavant or not. If order is irrelevant than the arrays can be sorted than biggest difference is largest difference beween the first and last element of the to arrays. And there are 5 different values in the two arrays.
Also since the values have one fractional digit the difference should be formated analog that it will be printed as 6.5

Comment: Yes you are right, should be int there.